# Can ASP.Net MVC 2 Custom attributes on class level and on property level be active in the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, custom-attributes, modelstate

I am working on asp.net mvc 2 web application.
I have model with 3 properties:

```
[IsCityInCountry("CountryID", "CityID"]
public class UserInfo
{
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
}
```

I have one "required" property attribute, and one attribute on class level :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class IsCityInCountry : ValidationAttribute
{
    public IsCityInCountry(string countryIDProperty, string cityIDProperty)
    {
        CountryIDProperty = countryIDProperty;
        CityIDProperty = cityIDProperty;
    }
    public string CountryIDProperty { get; set; }
    public string CityIDProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);

        var countryID = properties.Find(CountryIDProperty, true).GetValue(value);
        var cityID = properties.Find(CityIDProperty , true).GetValue(value);

        int countryIDInt;
        int.TryParse(countryID.ToString(), out countryIDInt);

        int cityIDInt;
        int.TryParse(cityID.ToString(), out cityIDInt);

        if (CountryBusiness.IsCityInCountry(countryIDInt, cityIDInt))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When I post the form on my view, and CountryID is not entered, in ModelState dictionary there's an error about that issue. Other attribute is ignored ("IsCityInCountry"). When I choose CountryID and CityID, which is not in selected country, I get appropriate validation message about that, and ModelState has another key (which is ""). I understand that advantage have property attributes and then class attributes. My question; is there any way to get all validation messages at the same time, no matter what kind of attributes are involved (class or property attributes)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC won't perform class level validation if there are property level validation errors. Brad Wilson explains this in his [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html):

> Earlier today, we committed a change to MVC 2 that converted the
>   validation system from Input Validation to Model Validation.
>
> What this means is that we will always run all validators on an
>   object, if that object had at least one value bound into it during
>   model binding. We run the property-level validators first, and if all
>   of those succeed, we'll run the model-level validators.

I would recommend you to go ahead and checkout [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) if you want to perform some more advanced validation in an ASP.NET MVC application. Declarative validation simply doesn't fit the bill in advanced validation scenarios.